# How to find out what API version Google Data API .NET Client library uses?

Tags: .net, gdata, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the .NET Client Library (version 2.2.0) for Google Data API:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list

I'm reading that Google is going to stop support API v2 for the Calendar API.  I'm not sure what version of the API the .NET Client library is using, or how to figure it out?  The Google Data .NET Client Library documentation is really poor.  I have the source code, but any tips on how to figure out what version of the API I'm using would be appreciated.

I suspect the GData .NET library uses APIv2 for Calendar, and is using APIv3 for Contacts, but am unsure/confused.

Mark

Comment: There is a blog for these deprecated apis, it [is here](http://googledataapis.blogspot.com/).  Yup, the blog is deprecated as well.  Google gets bored in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  Looking in the source code for GData .NET client library 2.2.0 you can see it is using APIv2 for the Calendar interface and APIv3 for the Contact interface.

versioninterfaces.cs:

```
public const int VersionTwo = 2;
public const int VersionThree = 3;
```

calendarservices.cs:

```
protected override void InitVersionInformation() {
    this.ProtocolMajor = VersionDefaults.VersionTwo;
}
```

contactservices.cs:

```
protected override void InitVersionInformation() {
    this.ProtocolMajor = VersionDefaults.VersionThree;
}
```